# Reset 'Load More Results' Testimonials when changing tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a simple 'about us' section with 2 tabs to switch between 'about' info and 'Testimonials' as can be seen at the following: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8z35gw1/)

As can be seen when selecting 'Testimonials' you have 2 testimonials shown by default and can reveal more by clicking button immediately beneath. I don't know a huge amount of jQuery but all I want is when clicking back to the 'About' tab; for the 'Testimonial' tab to reset back to its default ie just 2 Testimonials.

I tried giving a class to all new Testimonials and when clicking the 'about' tab making these 'hide()' which works  - but when you then click the 'load more' button; suddenly all the Testimonials show at once.

Ideally we would add a simple edit to the following to reset:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#aboutButton").click(function(){
$('#testimonials').hide();
$('#about').show();
});
```

PS I had to paste the js code for 'Testimonials' function in the html window on jsFiddle, don't know why it didn't work when inserted in 'Javascript' window...

Comment: You can simply hide them when the 'About' tab is shown: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/n0zLbf9p/. **However** the plugin doesn't reset the point it go to so when you click load more again all previous are shown instead of just one. There's no way around that as the plugin isn't made exceptionally well. I'd suggest finding another, or building your own. Also note that amount of inline CSS in that HTML is ridiculous, and most of it is repeated multiple times. Use external stylesheets. The length of your HTML code will be cut in half.

Comment: Keep 2 items hardcoded then add items using `$( ".whereYouWantToAdd" ).append( "<p>HTML here</p>" );` upon load more button click. When you switch back form about there will be 2 testimonials

Comment: Farhan - Thanks for the help. I have done I think as you suggest. Please see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tf6debjg/  But I can’t get it to work...You have to have at least 1 un-hardcoded testimonial showing by default in JS settings. Can you please update fiddle with working example?